# Best way to catch body onclick() even when iframe part of screen is clicked, to detect touch screen

Tags: javascript, android

I want to call a function at the exact moment when just anything is clicked or touched on web page.
Function is used to verify if there is touch screen used, and then I will open virtual keyboard.

This onclick does not seem to be called when the iframe part of screen is clicked?

```
<body onclick="openvirtual();" > 

function hasTouch() {
        try {
           document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
           return true;
        } catch (e) {
           return false;
        }    
    }

    var touchPresent = hasTouch();
    var clickedalready = 0;

    function openvirtual() {        
    console.warn("open virtual check" +touchPresent);

        if ((touchPresent) && (clickedalready == 0)) {
          //OPEN VIRTUAL KEYBOARD HERE           
          input.focus();
          clickedalready = 1;

        }
    return false;

    };
```

Comment: If you have control over the iframe contents, you can use `window.postMessage()` to pass messages between them to know when to create a click event on the main page. Is the iframe the virtual keyboard? If so, why does it have to be an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 
ontouchstart="openvirtual();"
I also had some problems with onclick method on mobile, but it solved me the problem.

Comment: does ontouchstart give error or failure,  with computer that has no touch screen?

Comment: on computer it's the same as onclick.